# Can the Least Squares Method be expressed as a convolution with a kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a laser line position estimation by fitting using the Least Square Method (LSM) and prove (or disprove) that it can be considered as a convolution with some function and finding the center by looking for the maximum (zero‐crossing by the derivative). What is the smoothing function?

The Least Square Method (LSM) is defined as:
$$\sum_i[S(x_i)-F(x_i,;a,b,\ldots)]^2=min,$$

where the fitting function is:
$$F(x;y_0,A,x_0,w)=y_0+A\cdot g(x-x_c,w)$$

The fit program will adjust all parameters, but we are interested only in x_c.

Hint: change sums to integrals in LSM description!
Relevant Equations  fitting function:

convolution:

Least Squares Method:
[image]
I started by converting the LSM from sum to integral form:
$$f(x_c)=\sum_i[S(x_i)-F(x_i,;a,b,\ldots)]^2tof(x_c)=\int(S(x)-F(x-x_c)^2dx$$

Since we are not interested in the other parameters (like offset), I assumed that they are fitted correctly and thus ignored them, turning $$F(x-x_c)$$ directly to $$g(x-x_c)$$

Then I expanded the binomial formula as following:
$$\int S(x)^2-2S(x)F(x-x_c)+g(x-x_c)^2dx$$

And used the linearity of the integral to isolate the part of the equation that doesn't depend on x_0:
$$f(x_c)=\int S(x)^2dx+\int2S(x)g(x-x_c)+g(x-x_c)^2dx$$

Hence, we have a constant q that isn't affected by the convolution:

$$f(x_c)=q+\int2S(x)g(x-x_c)+g(x-x_c)^2dx$$

The middle term is a convolution og the 2 functions. My idea was to disprove that a Kernel exists, because there is a term that doesn't depend on
, but this logic doesn't make any sense after thinking about it. I am completely stuck at this point, since I can neither prove nor disprove that the kernel function exists. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Might [math.se] or [stats.se] be better suited for this math/stats question?

Comment: probably. It's definetly physics, but you're right, the fact that we're dealing with lasers can be abstracted away to convolution math

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true under certain circumstances and then it is at the heart of *optimum radar* signal processing and was introduced by P. M. Woodward during WWII. It would be way too long to go through the whole issue but I just highlight here a few points. A standard and excellent reference is Difranco & Rubin: Radar Detection, Prentice-Hall 1968, Chapter 7.

**The problem setup** The simplest example: say you wish to estimate the range of a stationary target. You send out a signal $s(t)$ whose round trip delay (range) is $\tau$, so your radar receives a noisy signal $\tilde y(t)=As(t-\tau) + \tilde n(t)$ where $\tilde n(t)$ is a stationary receiver noise, normally distributed with uniform spectral density $\mathcal N_0$. The multiplier $A$ is the roundtrip transmitted attenuation signal suffers, and for the sake of this note we assume to be known. The receiver therefore knows everything about the signal that can be known except for the delay $\tau$, and our job is to make the best estimate that can be had.

**Solution** Since the received signal is distorted by the additive noise $\tilde n(t)$ whatever the term an *optimum solution* may mean it is understood in a probabilistic sense. In fact, if we knew the noise time function then we could calculate the unknown delay explicitly, the natural approach therefore is to consider the *a posteriori* probability distribution $\mathbf p (\tau|\tilde y)$, and using Bayes theorem this can be written as:
$$\mathbf p (\tau|\tilde y)\mathbf p (\tilde y) = \mathbf p(\tau) \mathbf p (\tilde y|\tau) \tag{1}$$
or $$\mathbf p (\tau|\tilde y) = \frac{\mathbf p(\tau) }{\mathbf p (\tilde y)} \mathbf p (\tilde y|\tau) 
\tag{2}$$

To simplify the problem we assume that target delay
is uniformly distributed over the reception window.
Note too that the *a priori* distribution $\mathbf p (\tilde y)$ is independent of $\tau$ therefore we can write the *a posteriori* distribution as
$$\mathbf p (\tau|\tilde y) =k\mathbf p (\tilde y|\tau) \tag{3}$$
where $k$ is independent of $\tau$. Therefore, in this special case, to maximize the *a posteriori* probability is the same as maximizing the so-called *likelihood* $\mathbf p (\tilde y|\tau)$. This can be done by noting that

$$\mathbf p (\tilde y|\tau) =\mathbf p (\tilde y|s(t-\tau) \\
=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\mathcal N_0}\int |\tilde y(t) -s(t-\tau)|^2dt\right]\tag{4} $$
To maximize Eq. (4) we should minimize the exponent, which is $$\frac{1}{\mathcal N_0}\int |\tilde y(t) -s(t-\tau)|^2dt,$$ resulting in the *least squares estimate*.

Now we are to minimize this integral for $\tau$:
$$\int |\tilde y(t) -s(t-\tau)|^2dt\\=\int |\tilde y(t)|^2dt +\int |s(t-\tau)|^2dt - 2\int \tilde y(t) s(t-\tau)dt \tag{5}$$

Both integrals, the energy of the received signal $\int |\tilde y(t)|^2dt$ and the energy of the transmitted signal but delayed by an arbitrary amount $\int |s(t-\tau)|^2dt$, are independent of $\tau$. There remains for us, therefore, to *maximize* the time correlation of the transmitted signal with the received signal:
$$\mathbf K[\tilde y(t), s(t-\tau)] = \int \tilde y(t) s(t-\tau)dt \tag{6}.$$

We can do this correlation explicitly by multiplying the received noisy signal $\tilde y(t)$ with a delayed local replica of the transmitted signal for every possible $\tau$ of interest and then integrating the product followed by selecting the largest of all to form our optimum estimate. But there is also another way because as you noticed one can view a convolution as being a correlation.

Specifically, introducing the time reversed function
$$\hat s (t)=s(-t) \tag{8}$$
we can write Eq (6) as follows:

$$\mathbf K[\tilde y(t), s(t-\tau)] = \int \tilde y(t) s(t-\tau)dt \\
=\int \tilde y(t) \hat s(\tau -t)dt \tag{9}.$$
In this form the correlation $\mathbf K[\tilde y(t), s(t-\tau)]$ is the result of the convolution of two time functions, namely, the received signal $\tilde y(t)$ with the impulse response $\hat s(t)$ of a *filter*. The filter  whose impulse response is $\hat s(t)$ is usually called the *matched* filter corresponding to the transmitted signal $s(t) = \hat s(-t)$.

It is not difficult to show that the *peak* level of the matched filter is actually the amplitude where signal to noise ratio is maximum.

Finally, it is worthwhile to mention that both correlation  receivers and matched filter receivers are widely used, one is no better than the other when the signal is buried in additive wide-sense stationary normally distributed noise. Their behavior is not the same if the interference is of a different class.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please clarify why $\int|s(t-\tau)|^2 dt$ is independent of Tau? Thanks in advance!

Comment: that quantity is just the *transmitted* energy delayed by  $\tau$; but formally let the integration boundaries, the full receiver window be a zillion times the length of the signal including all potential delays, say, infinity, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|s(t-\tau)|^2dt$ then it is obvious that this is independent of the delay.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!